# How to define a 4-4-5 week period in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My company uses a [4-4-5 calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar) for reporting purposes. Each month (aka period) is 4-weeks long, except every 3rd month is 5-weeks long.

Pandas seems to have good [support for custom calendar periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=frequency%20string#offset-aliases). However, I'm having trouble figuring out the correct frequency string or custom business month offset to achieve months for a 4-4-5 calendar.

For example:

```
df_index = pd.date_range("2020-03-29", "2021-03-27", freq="D", name="date")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=df_index, columns=["a"], data=np.random.randint(0, 100, size=len(df_index))
)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq="4W-SUN")).mean()
```

Grouping by 4-weeks starting on Sunday results in the following. The first three month start dates are correct but I need every third month to be 5-weeks long. The 4th month start date should be 2020-06-28.

```
                    a
date                 
2020-03-29  16.000000
2020-04-26  50.250000
2020-05-24  39.071429
2020-06-21  52.464286
2020-07-19  41.535714
2020-08-16  46.178571
2020-09-13  51.857143
2020-10-11  44.250000
2020-11-08  47.714286
2020-12-06  56.892857
2021-01-03  55.821429
2021-01-31  53.464286
2021-02-28  53.607143
2021-03-28  45.037037
```

Essentially what I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
                    a
date    
2020-03-29  20.000000
2020-04-26  50.750000
2020-05-24  49.750000
2020-06-28  49.964286
2020-07-26  52.214286
2020-08-23  47.714286
2020-09-27  46.250000
2020-10-25  53.357143
2020-11-22  52.035714
2020-12-27  39.750000
2021-01-24  43.428571
2021-02-21  49.392857
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing a similar problem as yourself. Were you able to find the solution? If so, could you please answer your question :)

Comment: No, I wasn’t able to come up with a solution

Comment: Would you happened to have any insights with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017473/how-to-create-a-4-4-5-calendar-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Pandas currently support only yearly and quarterly 5253 (aka 4-4-5 calendar).
See is [pandas.tseries.offsets.FY5253](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.FY5253.html) and [pandas.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter.html)

```
df_index = pd.date_range("2020-03-29", "2021-03-27", freq="D", name="date")
df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_index)
df['a'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, df.shape[0])
```

So indeed you need some more work to get to week level and maintain a 4-4-5 calendar. You could align to quarters using the native pandas offset and fill-in the 4-4-5 week pattern manually.

```
def date_range(start, end, offset_array, name=None):
    start = pd.to_datetime(start)
    end = pd.to_datetime(end)
    index = []

    start -= offset_array[0]
    while(start<end):
        for x in offset_array:
            start += x
            if start > end:
                break
            index.append(start)
    return pd.Series(index, name=name)
```

This function takes a list of offsets rather than a regular frequency period, so it allows to move from date to date following the offsets in the given array:

```
offset_445 = [
    pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(weekday=6),  
    4*pd.tseries.offsets.Week(weekday=6),
    4*pd.tseries.offsets.Week(weekday=6),
]

df_index_445 = date_range("2020-03-29", "2021-03-27", offset_445, name='date')


Out: 
0    2020-05-03
1    2020-05-31
2    2020-06-28
3    2020-08-02
4    2020-08-30
5    2020-09-27
6    2020-11-01
7    2020-11-29
8    2020-12-27
9    2021-01-31
10   2021-02-28
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Once the index is created, then it's back to aggregations logic to get the data in the right row buckets. Assuming that you want the mean for the start of each 4 or 5 week period, according to the `df_index_445` you have generated, it could look like this:

```
# calculate the mean on reindex groups
reindex = df_index_445.searchsorted(df.index, side='right') - 1
res = df.groupby(reindex).mean()

# filter valid output
res = res[res.index>=0]
res.index = df_index_445

Out:
                    a
2020-05-03  47.857143
2020-05-31  53.071429
2020-06-28  49.257143
2020-08-02  40.142857
2020-08-30  47.250000
2020-09-27  52.485714
2020-11-01  48.285714
2020-11-29  56.178571
2020-12-27  51.428571
2021-01-31  50.464286
2021-02-28  53.642857
```

Note that since the frequency is not regular, pandas will set the datetime index frequency to None.