# How to create a 4-4-5 fiscal calendar using python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, calendar

I would like to have a dataframe consisting of the corresponding week numbers and month every date from 1/1/21 to 31/12/50 would belong to. For instance,

```
  date  |   day   | week_no | yyyy-mm | quarter
01/01/21| Friday  |    40   | 2021-01 | Q4 2021
02/01/21| Saturday|    40   | 2021-01 | Q4 2021
.
.
24/01/21| Sunday  |    44   | 2021-02 | Q4 2021
.
.
01/04/21| Thursday|    53   | 2021-03 | Q4 2021
.
04/04/21| Sunday  |    1    | 2021-04 | Q1 2022
```

I found a wrapper class in Pandas called [FY5253Quarter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter.html) and [fiscal445](https://pypi.org/project/fiscal445/) in python, however, I am not sure how I can use this class to achieve what I require. Thanks in advance for all the help :)

Comment: this is a little easier to do in a RDMS as there are a plethora of stored procedures you can find. any reason you're using pandas ?

Comment: pandas is not necessary, you may also use python..because I thought pandas has a wrapper class, I thought it would be easier to use it make 4-4-5 calendar. Has to be python though because I am working on python :)

Comment: @Umar.H - you mean using SQL?

Comment: i do indeed, see [this link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12267/SQL-Server-Calendar-Table.html) sorry i should add that RDMS = relational database management system such as MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server etc.

Answer (score 1):

Creating calendar table could be done with SQL. Here example using PostgreSQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS date) d
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d+1
   FROM cte
   WHERE d < CAST('2030-12-31' AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
  d AS "date",
  to_char(d, 'DAY') AS day,
  to_char(d, 'iw') AS week_no,
  to_char(d, 'yyyy-mm') AS "yyyy-mm",
  to_char(d, '"Q"q yyyy') AS "quarter"
FROM cte;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dc1e459252c25d6ffe29235376d82ed5)**

How it works:

1. Recursive part generate date rows from `2021-01-01` to defined end date
2. Main query generate columns with proper string formatting

Now by having the query you could materialize it with `CREATE TABLE myCalendar AS ...` if needed.

If you are using different RDBMS, the pattern is basically the same - the only difference is using dialect specific functions.

For instance PostgreSQL has its own function `generate_series`:

```
SELECT * /* format functions here */
FROM generate_series(date '2021-01-01', date '2030-12-31', '1 day');
```

EDIT:

> How can I specify that I want a 4-4-5 calendar because from what I understand it seems you're creating a normal calendar?

Yes, here it is a normal calendar. The logic could be rewritten, but you already found a working solution.

> Also I found a link to PostgreSQL for fiscal 4-4-5 github.com/sqlsunday/calendar/blob/boss/CalendarFunctions.sql but I always meet with an error running the script for function Calendar.Fiscal_4_4_5

The point is it's written for SQL Server in TSQL as table-valued function. To call it use:

```
SELECT *
FROM  Calendar.Fiscal_4_4_5 ('2021-01-01', '2030-12-31', '2021-01-01','445',1);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9cba09eb2af432c55cecf6c6417181fe)**

Comment: Sorry I have never used SQL before. How can I re-use your code to fit my case?

Comment: @royalewithcheese Either call the query from Python or materialize table in DB and simply read from it `SELECT * FROM myCalendar`.

Comment: How can I specify that I want a 4-4-5 calendar because from what I understand it seems you're creating a normal calendar?

Comment: @royalewithcheese I have attached a live demo how to call this code

Comment: thanks for your help, but seems like I cannot use SQL. Have to find a way using Python.

Answer (score 1):

Okay Second try.
I like learning new things so thank you for bringing the 4-4-5 fiscal calender to my life. ;)

Since I think you only need to create this calender once and than use the finished calender as reference I thought of a stupid idea to create such a calender. Hardcoded loops.

The following code has a function that creates a 4-4-5 fiscal calender based on a start date and the number of years that should be created.
Since according to Wikipedia there is a leap week every 5 or 6 years I added the leap_week_year for you to choose in which year the leep week should go. Also a leap_week_quarter to choose which quarter should be 4-4-6.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def create_445_calender(start_date: str, years: int, leap_week_year = 5, leap_week_quarter = 4):

    output = []

    tmp_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
    
    for year in range(1,years+1):
        month_of_year = 1
        week_of_year = 1
        # 4 quarters
        for quarters in range(1,5):
            # 4 weeks
            for weeks in range(1,5):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1,8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year) if month_of_year >=  10 else '0' + str(month_of_year)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y') + '-' + tmp_monthstr
                    tmp_quarter = 'Q' + str(quarters) + ' ' + dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y')
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1
            # 4 weeks
            for weeks in range(1,5):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1,8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year) if month_of_year >=  10 else '0' + str(month_of_year)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y') + '-' + tmp_monthstr
                    tmp_quarter = 'Q' + str(quarters) + ' ' + dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y')
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1
            # 5 / 6 weeks
            # 5 years
            if (year % leap_week_year == 0 ) and (quarters == leap_week_quarter):
                tmp_weeks = 6
            else:
                tmp_weeks = 5
            for weeks in range(1,tmp_weeks+1):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1,8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year) if month_of_year >=  10 else '0' + str(month_of_year)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y') + '-' + tmp_monthstr
                    tmp_quarter = 'Q' + str(quarters) + ' ' + dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y')
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1

    df = pd.DataFrame(output,columns = ['date','day','week_no','yyyy-mm','quarter'])

    return df


my445calender = create_445_calender('06/04/2020', 6, 5, 4)
```

Comment: I identified an error in the way `yyyy-mm` and `quarter` is tracked at the start of a  year if it is not on a Sunday. For example, Jan 1, 2020 is on a wednesday. The `yyyy-mm` is 2020-12 instead of 2019-12 and the quarter is Q4 2020 instead of Q4 2019. This issue seems to be consistent throughout. Is there a way we can correct this? Otherwise the code is perfect.

Comment: Hi, should the Year of the quater and the year of the month always be the same?

01/01/2023,Sunday,39,2022-09,Q3 2022 ->
02/01/2023,Monday,40,2023-10,Q4 2023

or

01/01/2023,Sunday,39,2022-09,Q3 2022 ->
02/01/2023,Monday,40,2022-10,Q4 2022

Comment: I added a question directly addressing this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152070/year-transition-on-a-4-4-5-calendar-outputs-incorrect-year-on-yyyy-mm-and-quarte