# How to display the quarter for a given date using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a 4-4-5 calendar. I have a dataframe of dates from `29-03-2020` to `2022-04-09` consisting of their equivalent week number. `29-03-2020` is the starting date of the fiscal year. I am trying to generate a column with their respective quarters it would belong to.

Here is the final df I am looking for,

```
    a      |  count  | quarter
2020-04-04 |    1    | Q1 2021
2020-04-11 |    2    | Q1 2021
.
.
.
2021-03-27 |    52   | Q4 2021
2021-04-03 |    53   | Q4 2021           #since 2020 is a leap year there are 53 weeks otherwise it will be 52 weeks
2021-04-10 |    1    | Q1 2022
2021-04-17 |    2    | Q1 2022
.
2022-03-02 |    52   | Q4 2022
2022-04-09 |    1    | Q1 2023
```

I made the following attempt,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
year_start = '2020-03-29'
year_end = '2022-04-09'
week_end_sat = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(year_start, year_end, freq=f'W-SAT'), columns=['a'])
first_day_of_year = week_end_sat.iloc[0, 0].replace(day=1, month=1)
baseline = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(first_day_of_year, periods=len(week_end_sat), freq=f'W-SAT'), columns=['a'])
week_end_sat['count'] = baseline['a'].dt.isocalendar().week
week_end_sat['quarter'] = 'Q' + baseline['a'].dt.quarter.astype(str) + ' ' + (baseline['a'].dt.year+1).astype(str)
week_end_sat['b'] = baseline['a']
all_days_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(year_start, year_end), columns=['a'])
merge_df = pd.merge(all_days_df,week_end_sat, on='a', how='left')
merge_df['count'] = merge_df['count'].bfill()
merge_df['quarter'] = merge_df['quarter'].bfill()
merge_df['week_day'] = merge_df['a'].dt.day_name()
```

I get the quarters correct till week number 52, that is, Q4 2021 but after that it messes up. For 53rd week I get Q1 2022 and so on. Shouldn't it be Q4 2021 for 53rd week as well since it is a leap year? Could anyone guide me as to I may correct this?

EDIT

What if I also want to display the Month it belongs to for each date?

The **final df** should look like this,

```
   a       |  count  | quarter | month
2020-04-04 |    1    | Q1 2021 | 2020-04
2020-04-11 |    2    | Q1 2021 | 2020-04
.
.
.
2021-03-27 |    52   | Q4 2021 | 2021-03
2021-04-03 |    53   | Q4 2021 | 2021-03        
2021-04-10 |    1    | Q1 2022 | 2021-04
2021-04-17 |    2    | Q1 2022 | 2021-04
.
2022-03-02 |    52   | Q4 2022 | 2022-03
2022-04-09 |    1    | Q1 2023 | 2022-04
```

Comment: I don't get why leap year has anything to do with 53 weeks? You always have 53 weeks presenting in  a year (`365 = 7 * 52 + 1`).

Comment: Neither 365 nor 366 divides evenly by 7, so there will always be a 53rd week with less than 7 days in it.

Comment: What does your data originally look like?

Comment: originally it has the dates ending with Saturdays then I merge it with another dataframe consisting of all dates within the given range to find the week number. Now I attempted to calculate the corresponding quarters with the code in the question.

Comment: I am actually trying to create a 4-4-5 calendar but since I have no answers I moved on to a different path to solve my problem. The question can be found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017473/how-to-create-a-4-4-5-fiscal-calendar-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `year_start` is always the start of a fiscal year, you can do this with a `for` loop:

```py
# Generate a week-to-accounting-month mapping
m = np.roll(np.arange(1, 13, dtype='int'), -3)
w = np.tile([4,4,5], 4)

acct_month = {
    index + 1: month
        for index, month in enumerate(np.repeat(m, w))
}
acct_month[53] = 3 # week 53, if exists, always belong to month 3

#
data = []
y, week = year_start.year, 1
month = year_start.replace(month=4, day=1)

# A fiscal year has 53 weeks if it starts on a leap year. 52 weeks otherwise
num_week = lambda: 53 if (y % 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0) or (y % 400 == 0) else 52

for date in pd.date_range(year_start, year_end, freq='7D'):
    data.append((date + pd.Timedelta(days=6), y+1, week, month))
    
    week += 1
    if week > num_week():
        y += 1
        week = 1
        
    if acct_month[week] != month.month:
        month += pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['week_end', 'fy', 'week_no', 'acct_month'])

# Q1, Q2 and Q3 always have 13 weeks
# Q4 may have 13 or 14 weeks
q = np.ceil(df['week_no'].div(13).clip(upper=4)).astype('int')
df['quarter'] = 'Q' + q.astype(str) + ' ' + df['fy'].astype(str)
```

Result:

```
      week_end    fy  week_no acct_month  quarter
0   2020-04-04  2021        1 2020-04-01  Q1 2021
1   2020-04-11  2021        2 2020-04-01  Q1 2021
2   2020-04-18  2021        3 2020-04-01  Q1 2021
3   2020-04-25  2021        4 2020-04-01  Q1 2021
...
48  2021-03-06  2021       49 2021-03-01  Q4 2021
49  2021-03-13  2021       50 2021-03-01  Q4 2021
50  2021-03-20  2021       51 2021-03-01  Q4 2021
51  2021-03-27  2021       52 2021-03-01  Q4 2021
52  2021-04-03  2021       53 2021-03-01  Q4 2021
53  2021-04-10  2022        1 2021-04-01  Q1 2022
54  2021-04-17  2022        2 2021-04-01  Q1 2022
55  2021-04-24  2022        3 2021-04-01  Q1 2022
...
100 2022-03-05  2022       48 2022-03-01  Q4 2022
101 2022-03-12  2022       49 2022-03-01  Q4 2022
102 2022-03-19  2022       50 2022-03-01  Q4 2022
103 2022-03-26  2022       51 2022-03-01  Q4 2022
104 2022-04-02  2022       52 2022-03-01  Q4 2022
105 2022-04-09  2023        1 2022-04-01  Q1 2023
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question (since I am trying to implement a 4-4-5 calendar) , is it possible to use the same logic to find the corresponding month to each date it belongs to? For example, April (starting month of the fiscal year), July, October, January, May, August, November, February always have four weeks followed by June, September, December having five weeks and March(end of a fiscal year) having 5 or 6 weeks depending upon whether year is leap year or not. I think it might be similar to the quarter logic? Could you please help me implement that as well?

Comment: I have edited the question where I have added the corresponding month column respective to the dates.

Comment: See my edited answer for adding the accounting month

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. One question, what is the year_start is not the first day of the fiscal year? When I update your code to `for date in pd.date_range(year_start, year_end, freq='W-SAT'):` (since the dates always end on a Saturday) then I get the wrong results. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: oh I think I understand, after changing the code above, I can also update this line `data.append(date, y+1, week, month)` and it should work fine right?