# Year transition on a 4-4-5 calendar outputs incorrect year on yyyy-mm and quarter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I created a 4-4-5 calendar by repurposing some code here:
[How to create a 4-4-5 fiscal calendar using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017473/how-to-create-a-4-4-5-fiscal-calendar-using-python)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def create_445_calender(start_date: str, years: int, leap_week_year = 5, leap_week_quarter = 4):

    output = []

    tmp_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%m/%d/%Y')
    
    for year in range(1,years+1):
        month_of_year = 1
        week_of_year = 1
        # 4 quarters
        for quarters in range(1,5):
            # 4 weeks
            for weeks in range(1,5):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1,8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%m/%d/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year) if month_of_year >=  10 else '0' + str(month_of_year)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y') + '-' + tmp_monthstr
                    tmp_quarter = 'Q' + str(quarters) + ' ' + dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y')
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1
            # 4 weeks
            for weeks in range(1,5):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1,8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%m/%d/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year) if month_of_year >=  10 else '0' + str(month_of_year)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y') + '-' + tmp_monthstr
                    tmp_quarter = 'Q' + str(quarters) + ' ' + dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y')
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1
            # 5 / 6 weeks
            # 5 years
            if (year % leap_week_year == 0 ) and (quarters == leap_week_quarter):
                tmp_weeks = 6
            else:
                tmp_weeks = 5
            for weeks in range(1,tmp_weeks+1):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1,8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%m/%d/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year) if month_of_year >=  10 else '0' + str(month_of_year)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y') + '-' + tmp_monthstr
                    tmp_quarter = 'Q' + str(quarters) + ' ' + dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%Y')
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1

    df = pd.DataFrame(output,columns = ['date','day','week_no','yyyy-mm','quarter'])
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    return df


cal = create_445_calender('01/01/2012', 30, 5, 4)
```

However, I found a bug in this code. If the year ends on a day that's not Saturday, the subsequent year will be printed instead of the previous year in the `yyyy-mm` field and `quarter` columns.

If you run the above code, you'll face two scenarios:

Scenario 1 (most common):

```
date        day         week_no    yyyy-mm  quarter
12/30/12    Sunday      1          2012-01  Q1 2012
12/31/12    Monday      1          2012-01  Q1 2012
1/1/13      Tuesday     1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/2/13      Wednesday   1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/3/13      Thursday    1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/4/13      Friday      1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/5/13      Saturday    1          2013-01  Q1 2013
```

`week_no` is consistently correct but the `yyyy-mm` and `quarter` should be the year 2013 for the month of December. (one year higher than it current is).

What it should be:

```
date        day         week_no    yyyy-mm  quarter
12/30/12    Sunday      1          2013-01  Q1 2013
12/31/12    Monday      1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/1/13      Tuesday     1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/2/13      Wednesday   1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/3/13      Thursday    1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/4/13      Friday      1          2013-01  Q1 2013
1/5/13      Saturday    1          2013-01  Q1 2013
```

However, sometimes there will be a year with 53 weeks. In the case of 53 weeks, the year for January needs to be one number lower than it currently is.

Scenario 2 (only on 53 week years):

```
date        day         week_no   yyyy-mm   quarter
12/26/21    Sunday      53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/27/21    Monday      53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/28/21    Tuesday     53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/29/21    Wednesday   53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/30/21    Thursday    53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/31/21    Friday      53        2021-12   Q4 2021
1/1/22      Saturday    53        2022-12   Q4 2022
```

This is how it should look:

```
date        day         week_no   yyyy-mm   quarter
12/26/21    Sunday      53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/27/21    Monday      53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/28/21    Tuesday     53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/29/21    Wednesday   53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/30/21    Thursday    53        2021-12   Q4 2021
12/31/21    Friday      53        2021-12   Q4 2021
1/1/22      Saturday    53        2021-12   Q4 2021
```

The question here is how do we correct the year value for both `yyyy-mm` and `quarter` so that it satisfies both scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

This code has two issues: The first problem is that `tmp_yyyy_mm` is using `dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime, '%Y')`, which produces the regular calendar year rather than 4-4-5 calendar year.

To fix this, we just need to record the starting year (`start_year`) before generating the 4-4-5 calendar and add up the years passed within the 4-4-5 calendar by `str(start_year + year - 1)`.

and if the starting year happens to be in the first week of the 4-4-5 calendar, there might be a year-crossing in the first week. Therefore, the `start_year` should be determined based on the year of the last day of the starting week.

The second problem is the frequency of years with 53 weeks (`leap_week_year`) in 4-4-5 calendar, which may not be fixed. In the 4-4-5 calendar, a year with 52 weeks has 364 days, while in the regular calendar, a year has 365 days.
Therefore, ideally, there should be an extra week every 6 years in the 4-4-5 calendar. However, we also need to consider leap years that occur every four years, such as 2012, 2016, 2020. Leap years have 366 days (an extra day on February 29th).

a simple way to determine whether the years with 53 weeks or not is based on whether there are 7 days remaining or not after the 52nd weeks in this year.

The modified code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def create_445_calendar(start_date: str, years: int, leap_week_quarter:int = 4):
    tmp_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%d/%m/%Y')   
    start_week_end_day = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=6)
    start_year = start_week_end_day.year

    output = []
    for year in range(1, years + 1):
        month_of_year = 1
        week_of_year = 1
        # 4 quarters
        for quarter in range(1, 5):
            # 4 weeks
            for week in range(1, 5):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1, 8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')
                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year).zfill(2)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = f"{str(start_year + year - 1)}-{tmp_monthstr}"
                    tmp_quarter = f"Q{str(quarter)} {str(start_year + year - 1)}"
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1
            # 4 weeks
            for week in range(1, 5):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1, 8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')

                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year).zfill(2)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = f"{str(start_year + year - 1)}-{tmp_monthstr}"
                    tmp_quarter = f"Q{str(quarter)} {str(start_year + year - 1)}"
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1
            # 5 weeks
            for week in range(1, 6):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1, 8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    tmp_weekday = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime,'%A')

                    tmp_monthstr = str(month_of_year).zfill(2)
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = f"{str(start_year + year - 1)}-{tmp_monthstr}"
                    tmp_quarter = f"Q{str(quarter)} {str(start_year + year - 1)}"
                    output.append([tmp_datestr,tmp_weekday, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1
            month_of_year += 1

            # extra week
            # If there are 7 days remaining after the 52nd weeks in each year,
            # this year in 4-4-5 calendar will have an extra week.

            # The remaining days after the 52nd week in each year increase by
            # one day every year because in the 4-4-5 calendar, a year with 52 weeks has 364 days, 
            # while in the regular calendar, a year has 365 days.                 
            # Therefore, a year with 53 weeks occurs approximately every 6 years. 
            # However, the frequency of year with 53 weeks is irregular because 
            # some years (leap years) may have 366 days, so a simple way to determine 
            # whether a year with 53 weeks should based on the remaining days after the 52nd week.            
            has_53_weeks_this_year = tmp_datetime.year == \
                                    (tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=6)).year
            if has_53_weeks_this_year and (quarter == leap_week_quarter):
                # 7 days
                for days in range(1, 8):
                    tmp_datestr = dt.datetime.strftime(tmp_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
                    tmp_monthstr = 12
                    tmp_yyyy_mm = f"{str(start_year + year - 1)}-{tmp_monthstr}"
                    tmp_quarter = f"Q{str(quarter)} {str(start_year + year - 1)}"
                    output.append(
                        [tmp_datestr, week_of_year, tmp_yyyy_mm, tmp_quarter])
                    tmp_datetime = tmp_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=1)
                week_of_year += 1

    return pd.DataFrame(output,columns = ['date','day','week_no','yyyy-mm','quarter'])


cal = create_445_calendar('01/01/2012', 30, 5, 4)
```

Output:

```
cal.query("date.isin(['29/12/2012', '30/12/2012', '31/12/2012', '01/01/2013', 
                      '02/01/2013', '03/01/2013', '04/01/2013', '05/01/2013'])")
```

|  | date | day | week_no | yyyy-mm | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 363 | 29/12/2012 | Saturday | 52 | 2012-12 | Q4 2012 |
| 364 | 30/12/2012 | Sunday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |
| 365 | 31/12/2012 | Monday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |
| 366 | 01/01/2013 | Tuesday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |
| 367 | 02/01/2013 | Wednesday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |
| 368 | 03/01/2013 | Thursday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |
| 369 | 04/01/2013 | Friday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |
| 370 | 05/01/2013 | Saturday | 1 | 2013-01 | Q1 2013 |

```
cal.query("date.isin(['26/12/2021', '27/12/2021', '28/12/2021', '29/12/2021', 
                      '30/12/2021', '31/12/2021', '01/01/2022', '02/01/2022'])")
```

|  | date | day | week_no | yyyy-mm | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3647 | 26/12/2021 | Sunday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3648 | 27/12/2021 | Monday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3649 | 28/12/2021 | Tuesday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3650 | 29/12/2021 | Wednesday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3651 | 30/12/2021 | Thursday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3652 | 31/12/2021 | Friday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3653 | 01/01/2022 | Saturday | 53 | 2021-12 | Q4 2021 |
| 3654 | 02/01/2022 | Sunday | 1 | 2022-01 | Q1 2022 |